# Read a TXT file and transform it into a SQL script

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, converters

I have a txt file:

```
LoginId; No_Intervenant
EF2KBT0; 1003820030
ENHD0KE; 1003820129
E9PM7EP; 1003820153
EFT10OO; 1003820218
```

I need to create another txt file, that contains an sql UPDATE script from this information like:

```
UPDATE Contact
Set
Contact.No_Intervenant = '1003820030'
where
ISNULL (Contact.LoginId, '') = 'ER7OZXZ';
```

I only got this result using a `Stringbuilder` method, but performing hardcode. What I would like is for the header to be added automatically.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private static void AddSqlCommand(StringBuilder sql, string[] columns, string[] types, string[] values)
{
    sql.AppendLine("UPDATE Contact");
    sql.AppendLine("SET");
    //skip LoginId columns
    for (int i = 1; i < columns.Length; i++)
    {
        switch (types[i].Trim())
        {
            case "int":                      
                sql.Append($"   Contact.{columns[i].Trim()} = {values[i]}");
                //sql.Append($" Contact.{columns[0].TrimStart() } = {values[i]}");
                break;
            default:
                sql.Append($"   Contact.No_Intervenant = '{values[i]}'");
                break;
        }
        if (columns.Length > 1 && i != columns.Length - 1)
        {
            sql.Append(",");
        }
        sql.AppendLine();
    }
    sql.AppendLine("WHERE");
    sql.AppendLine($"   ISNULL(Contact.LoginId, '') = '{values[0]}';");
    sql.AppendLine();
}

private static StringBuilder GenerateSqlScript(string[] fileContent)
{
    var sqlCommand = new StringBuilder();
    string[] types = fileContent[0].Split(';');
    string[] columns = fileContent[1].Split(';');
    //skip the first line (header)
    for (int i = 2; i < fileContent.Length; i++)
    {
        string[] values = fileContent[i].Split(';');
        if (values.Length >= 1)
        {
            AddSqlCommand(sqlCommand, columns, types, values);
        }
    }
    return sqlCommand;
}
```

How could I get and Add the header automaticaly? Because I'll probably have to do this for longer files, with more columns and more Update lines for other files, and I would not like to hardcode all the headers of the files, like the example I'll have to do next:

Header:

> No_Intervenant;First_Name;Last_Name;Role_SE;EMail;Phone;Extension;Statut;Address_1;Address_2;Zip;CPF;Inscription_Particulier;DHM_Stat_Part;Date_via_ClicSeQur;Last_Update;

Data:

> 1003820030;NOEL;SANTOS;Particulier;;;;Actif;1528 STREET;VAL-D''OR CA;AAA 5T9;123456789;Actif;;2016-07-19 09:49:43;2019-02-08 14:24:19;

Comment: Parse as CSV with `;` as delimiter

Comment: if the task is mainly just to import all those data to a sql table, just format your text file to be CSV and import to sql table using sql management studio ( i presume you are using tsql)

Comment: the sql script that I generate will be imported to another system (crm), and this system takes care of reading this sql script file to update a database

Comment: I don't understand how you are setting the type[] from the fileContents. It only looks like it has the column names and values?

Comment: You will want to consider SQL Injection also.

Comment: Another approach you may wish to consider is to `bcp` / bulk insert this into a table. Then the updates will be much faster since they can all be done by joining on the server, rather than one at a time `UPDATE` scripts.

Comment: I don't see why you need to use `ISNULL` in that script unless you expect to get blank long-in ids that should map to nulls in the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you only need a couple of simple changes to your string interpolation, see below. If you have a update that affects multiple tables you should append your table name to the column in the array.

Here is how I tested, according to your logic the first row of the file should contain your data types (the example you posted doesn't). So either your logic is wrong or the data sample is wrong. It works with the test code.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var line = new List<string>();
            line.Add("string;string");
            line.Add("LoginId; No_Intervenant");
            line.Add("EF2KBT0; 1003820030");
            line.Add("ENHD0KE; 1003820129");
            line.Add("E9PM7EP; 1003820153");
            line.Add("EFT10OO; 1003820218");

            var fileContent = line.ToArray();

            var sqlCommand = new StringBuilder();
            string[] types = fileContent[0].Split(';');
            string[] columns = fileContent[1].Split(';');

            //skip the first line (header)
            for (int i = 2; i < fileContent.Length; i++)
            {
                string[] values = fileContent[i].Split(';');

                if (values.Length >= 1)
                {
                    AddSqlCommand(sqlCommand, columns, types, values, "client");
                }
            }

        }
```

Edited Fuction:

```
private static void AddSqlCommand(StringBuilder sql, string[] columns, string[] types, string[] values, string table)
            {
                sql.AppendLine($"UPDATE {table}");
                sql.AppendLine("SET");

                //skip LoginId columns
                for (int i = 1; i < columns.Length; i++)
                {
                    switch (types[i].Trim())
                    {
                        case "int":
                            sql.Append($"   {columns[i].Trim()} = {values[i]}");
                            break;

                        default:
                            sql.Append($"   {columns[i].Trim()} = '{values[i]}'");
                            break;
                    }

                    if (columns.Length > 1 && i != columns.Length - 1)
                    {
                        sql.Append(",");
                    }

                    sql.AppendLine();
                }

                sql.AppendLine("WHERE");
                sql.AppendLine($"   ISNULL({columns[0].Trim()}, '') = '{values[0]}';");
                sql.AppendLine();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Sorry. Did not work. See the results:

    UPDATE {table}
    SET
   Contact.1003820030 = 1003820129
WHERE
   ISNULL(EF2KBT0, '') = 'ENHD0KE';

UPDATE {table}
SET
   Contact.1003820030 = 1003820153
WHERE
   ISNULL(EF2KBT0, '') = 'E9PM7EP';

UPDATE {table}
SET
   Contact.1003820030 = 1003820218
WHERE
   ISNULL(EF2KBT0, '') = 'EFT10OO';

Comment: I have updated the code with my test code. Either you logic is wrong or you test file doesn't match the logic. I am referring to where you set the types: string[] types = fileContent[0].Split(';');

Answer (score 0):

I believe in this case the 'MERGE' will be a perfect solution.
It could be something like:

```
-- HEADER --
MERGE [your table] as trg
USING (VALUES

-- DATA FROM THE FILE --
(id, intervenant),
(id, intervenant)

-- FOOTER
) as src(id, intervenant)
ON [your logic from the WHERE statement]
WHEN MATCHED UPDATE SET
trg.[your column] = src.[your column];
```

Answer (score 0):

The data from the source file can be loaded into a `DataTable` object, with `UPDATE` statements then constructed from this.  The header names from the file are obtained from the `Columns` property of the `DataTable`, then used to specify the columns used in the `UPDATE` script.  In the example below, additional lines and the `GO` separator are added in the script for formatting.  These aren't essential and can be removed if you prefer to.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;



     //get source file
    string fullFileName = @"C:\Input Folder\SourceFile.txt";

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    //output .sql script
    string sqlScript = @"C:\Output Folder\UpdateScript.SQL";

   using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fullFileName))
    {
    string firstLine = sr.ReadLine();
    string[] headers = firstLine.Split(';');

    //define columns for data table
    foreach (string h in headers)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(h);
    }

    int columnCount = dt.Columns.Count;

    string line = sr.ReadLine();

    while (line != null)
    {
    string[] fields = line.Split(';');

    int currentLength = fields.Count();

    if (currentLength < columnCount)
    {
        while (currentLength < columnCount)
        {
            line += sr.ReadLine();
            currentLength = line.Split(';').Count();
        }
        fields = line.Split(';');
    }
    //load data table
    dt.Rows.Add(fields);
    line = sr.ReadLine();
   }

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
       {
        sb.AppendLine("UPDATE Contact SET " + dt.Columns[1] + " = '" + dr[1] + 
      "' WHERE ISNULL(" + dt.Columns[0] + ", '') = '" + dr[0] + "'");

        //extra lines and GO batch separator added between UPDATE statements for formating
        sb.AppendLine(Environment.NewLine);
        sb.AppendLine("GO");
        sb.AppendLine(Environment.NewLine);
       }   
            //output UPDATE commands as .sql script file
            File.WriteAllText(sqlScript, sb.ToString());
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to post an update of the code that I updated and that at the moment works perfectly. Thank you all for the answers and for helping me.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GenererScriptSQL
```

{
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private static void AddSqlCommand(StringBuilder sql, string[] columns, string[] types, string[] values)
    {
        sql.AppendLine("UPDATE Contact");
        sql.AppendLine("SET");

        //skip LoginId columns
        for (int i = 1; i < columns.Length; i++)
        {
            switch (types[i].Trim())
            {
                case "int":

                    sql.Append($"   Contact.{columns[i].Trim()} = {values[i]}");

                    break;

                default:
                    sql.Append($"   Contact.{columns[i].Trim()} = '{values[i]}'");
                    break;
            }

            if (columns.Length > 1 && i != columns.Length - 1)
            {
                sql.Append(",");
            }

            sql.AppendLine();
        }

        sql.AppendLine();

        sql.AppendLine("WHERE");

        sql.AppendLine();

        sql.AppendLine($"   Contact.{columns[0].Trim()} = '{values[0]}'");

        sql.AppendLine();


    }

    private static StringBuilder GenerateSqlScript(string[] fileContent)
    {
        var sqlCommand = new StringBuilder();
        string[] types = fileContent[0].Split(';');
        string[] columns = fileContent[0].Split(';');

        //skip the first line(header)

        for (int i = 1; i < fileContent.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] values = fileContent[i].Split(';');

            if (values.Length >= 1)
            {
                AddSqlCommand(sqlCommand, columns, types, values);
            }
        }

        return sqlCommand;
    }

    private void buttonCreateSqlFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (IsFileSelected())
            {
                string[] fileContent = File.ReadAllLines(textBoxFile.Text);

                if (fileContent != null)
                {
                    StringBuilder sqlCommand = GenerateSqlScript(fileContent);

                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sqlCommand.ToString()))
                    {
                        WriteSqlFile(sqlCommand);
                    }
                }


            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sélectionner le fichier de chargement.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void buttonSelectFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var fileBrowser = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                if (fileBrowser.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    textBoxFile.Text = fileBrowser.FileName;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    private bool IsFileSelected()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxFile.Text) && File.Exists(textBoxFile.Text);
    }

    private void WriteSqlFile(StringBuilder sqlCommand)
    {
        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(textBoxFile.Text);
        string BackupDate = fileInfo.Name + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm") + "_Update" + ".sql";


        string sqlFilePath = Path.Combine(fileInfo.Directory.FullName, BackupDate);

        if (File.Exists(sqlFilePath))
        {
            File.Delete(sqlFilePath);
        }

        File.WriteAllText(sqlFilePath, sqlCommand.ToString());

        MessageBox.Show($@" Le fichier sql a été générée! {sqlFilePath}");
    }
}
```

}